# Use Getter to get data from static class and update data at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

**The Background**

So I have schedule data that is shared across multiple viewmodels in my WPF application. So I decided to put it in a static class that can easily be accessed from any viewModel that needs it.

The static class holds an observableCollection of the schedule data (`ScheduleObject`) that I need (including times, operations to complete, etc).

When a particular VM wants to use the data it calls the static observable collection through a static function and attempts to put the `ScheduleObject` inside a new wrapper class I made `ScheduleDisplayObject` that adds a `SolidColorBrush` variable so I am able to highlight different scheduleobjects with different colors based on different conditions.

**The Issue**

When I run the program, my ItemsControl that the `DisplayObjects` ObservableCollection is attached to fills as intended. In the constructor of the VM, I try to set the color inside the wrapper class to something different to indicate a certain ItemsControl item is important. It does not update. I am not able to update the color in the wrapper class. Now I assume this is because every time `DisplayObjects` (See Below) is called on, it calls the getter again and recreates the entire list of wrappers without my color modifications.

I am wondering what is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

All relevant code is below. `RaisePropertyChanged` and `ObservableClass` are implementations of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Please let me know if you have any questions!

```
public VM
{
        /// <summary>
        /// A UI consumable list of display objects that hold tube schedule information
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ScheduleDisplayObject> DisplayObjects
        {
            get
            {
                var list = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleDisplayObject>();
                foreach (ScheduleObject item in ScheduleManager.getList())
                {
                    list.Add(new ScheduleDisplayObject(item));
                }
                return list;
            }
        }


        public VM()
        {
            DisplayObjects[0].BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); //This doesn't do anything
        }
}


public static class ScheduleManager
{
        static ObservableCollection<ScheduleObject> ScheduleObjects = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleObject>();

        public static ObservableCollection<ScheduleObject> getList()
        {
            return ScheduleObjects;
        }
}



    public class ScheduleDisplayObject : ObservableClass
    {

        #region Declarations
        private SolidColorBrush _backgroundColor;
        /// <summary>
        /// Background color of the UI item
        /// </summary>
        public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return _backgroundColor; }
            set
            {
                _backgroundColor = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ScheduleObject _scheduleObject;
        /// <summary>
        /// Object containing schedule data for each tube
        /// </summary>
        public ScheduleObject ScheduleObject
        {
            get { return _scheduleObject; }
            set
            {
                _scheduleObject = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public ScheduleDisplayObject(int r, int c)
        {
            ScheduleObject = new ScheduleObject(r, c);
        }

        public ScheduleDisplayObject(ScheduleObject s)
        {
            ScheduleObject = s;
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class ScheduleObject : ObservableClass
    {
        //Data (strings, doubles, ints, etc)

    }
```

Comment: Put your color changes in the getter instead of the constructor, or make your observable collection a member of the class so that you don't recreate it every time the getter fires.

Comment: You rewrite you collection every time getting it

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess my problem is, how would I effectively make it accessible to other ViewModels if it is a member of this VM? It feels gross to use static members in ViewModels

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yeah, I started to realize that was happening, is there a good way to not rewrite my collection every time and have it be accessed from this static class?

Comment: Storing a static reference to a collection you made somewhere is an unremarkable operation.  I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a backing field for `ObservableCollection<ScheduleDisplayObject>`, it prevents it being overwritten every time

```cs
private ObservableCollection<ScheduleDisplayObject> _displayObjects;
public ObservableCollection<ScheduleDisplayObject> DisplayObjects
{
    get
    {
        if (_displayObjects == null)
        {
            _displayObjects = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleDisplayObject>();
            foreach (ScheduleObject item in ScheduleManager.getList())
            {
                _displayObjects.Add(new ScheduleDisplayObject(item));
            }
        }

        return _displayObjects;
    }
}
```

If you update this information during app runtime, it'll make sense to implement both getter and setter for collection to reflect the data changes

Comment: Thank you, It looks like this works! When I add new stuff to the static collection I make sure to set the _displayObjects = null and then do RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayObjects") to make it regenerate the list, but it does work setting the color. Thank you